# How to reset the serial number?

Tags: nodes

I have created a content type to which I added a [Serial Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/serial) number. For testing purposes, I created many nodes.

Now I would like to reset the value of the serial number, so that the next created node will have 1 as serial number. Can anyone help me how to do this?

I found [this document](https://www.drupal.org/node/834140), which suggests to delete the field, but I don't want to delete the serial number field.

Comment: truncate db table ?

Comment: @BipinK:  need to print the serial number from first  say 1

Comment: Truncate will reset the serial number 1

Comment: so what exactly do i need to perform in this case.

Comment: do i need to write a query after clicking on the table in the database?

Comment: you can write `TRUNCATE tablename`; on selecting the database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30195/discussion-between-rose-and-bipin-k).

Comment: On Drupal, truncating a database table is never a good idea. Chances are there are more database tables referring that table's content.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: yea  more database tables referring that table's content.will it effect by any chance

Comment: The correct way to remove field's data is using the correct API and let Drupal invoke the necessary hooks.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: remove field's data is using the correct API...means? what exactly  need to do?